# Searching SQLite3 database with WHERE clause

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

**My code:**

```
   name1 = name_entry.get()
    conn = sqlite3.connect('test123.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute("SELECT * FROM table123 WHERE name = name1")
    print(c.fetchall())
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

**Error:**

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: name1
```

**My question**
How do I use a variable with WHERE caluse to find the desired tuples ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should substitute the variable `name1` value in your `c.execute` statement. Do this:

```
c.execute("SELECT * FROM table123 WHERE name = {}".format(name1))
```

**OR:**

```
c.execute("SELECT * FROM table123 WHERE name = ?", name1)
```